# Svn to Mercurial: Fewer revision numbers and missing tags

Tags: svn, mercurial

I want to migrate my project (https://softsmithy.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/softsmithy) from Subversion to Mercurial.
I'm working on a local mirror (svnsync; as described at http://panospace.wordpress.com/2010/05/19/svn2hg_part1/ ).
The current svn revision number is: 544
I'm using the following command to convert the subversion Repository to a Mercurial repository:
hg convert --branchsort --authors svn_users.txt softsmithy-mirror softsmithy-mercurial-all

The resulting repository doesn't contain all tags, though.

The resulting repository also does have only 511 revisions. I'm not sure if this is only related to the tags.

Some of the missing tags are tagging a subdirectory of trunk. This might be a part of the problem.

How can I get all tags and revisions?

Regards,
Puce

Comment: sadly this might be something only the mercurial mailing list can help with. I wish you luck on getting it converted, I know how important retaining the old tag structure can be and is.

Comment: I don't like to sign up to mailing lists for a single question, but you might be right. I cross-posted it there. (Don't have the archive link yet.)

Answer (score 2):

You might re-try the conversion using the [hgsubversion extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgSubversion). It's designed to allow two-way use of a Subversion repository from Mercurial, but as a consequence it can sometimes handle a simple one-way conversion better (and faster).

Neither `hg convert` nor hgsubversion will likely be able to handle subdir tags automatically, though. You might have to manually add the tags after the conversion. If you're using a current version of hg (>= 1.6), this can be done relatively easily:

```
$ svn log svn://example.com/original/repo/tags/subdirtag  # note revision number
$ hg tag -r 'svnrev(X)' TAGNAME                           # X is revision number
```

Comment: Hi Kevin,
Thanks for your response. Yes, I've found hgsubversion, too, and it seems to do the better job (e.g. hg convert did loose histories of moved files). I used hg convert afterwards for some clean-up (e.g. renaming users). The hg tag command didn't work the way mentioned, but I used the hg view tool to create the missing tags manually (fewer tags were missing).

The only thing: I have now two small branches and about 10 heads in the repo, which I don't really need. Is there an easy way to remove those without corrupting the repo?

Answer (score 0):

You can read about subdir tags and the problem they cause and how to fix it under [cvs2hg: Mercurial backend for cvs2svn](http://vc.gerg.ca/hg/cvs2svn/raw-file/tip/README.cvs2hg)

The tool [cvs2hg](http://hg.gerg.ca/cvs2svn/) might also help to convert to mercurial if you can convert from SVN to CVS without information loss.  It can be configured to be adapted to the kind of conversion you want to make (there is no 1:1 translation some interpretation takes place).

Comment: Hmm, I don't feel comfortable with converting back to CVS first. I think I could loose much information (e.g. file histories, when files were renamed/ moved). Or don't you see any issues there and it's safe?

Comment: Yes that really is an issue, renames history will probably be lost when going to CVS, OTOH the tag handling of cvs2hg is much better and more flexible.  I fear you can't have everything here. Well considering safety, you might try different ways and compare the results, its not that the conversion is destructive.